# Restoring postgres database except certain tables with pg_restore

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql dump (created with pg_dump, custom compressed format). I would like to pg_restore it onto another server except a few large tables.  I have tried using -l option and remove the tables not needed from the list as shown below. Is there an effective solution as am not sure how efficient the below is.

```
pg_restore  -l dumpfile.dmp > list.txt
egrep -v "logtable|summarytable|historytable" list.txt > listex.txt
pg_restore -Fc -v -p 5432 -d prism  --use-list=listex.txt  dumpfile.dmp  2>> error1.out &
```

Comment: What's the question? Everything is working fine, as far as I can see